# Don't reserve space in a CSS Grid if the element doesn't exist / is optional

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using grid-template to set up a simple grid structure for one row and four columns. The two leftmost columns have a fixed width, and the remaining two should fill the remaining space.

However, the second column is **optional** - it may not be present at all. In this case I do not want to reserve any space for it. The two rightmost columns should fill the space.

This is obviously not possible with grid-template. Is it possible at all?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one two three four";
  grid-template-columns: 8rem 8rem 1fr 1fr;
}

.one   { background: #404788aa; grid-area: one;   }
.two   { background: #287d8eaa; grid-area: two;   }
.three { background: #3cbb75aa; grid-area: three; }
.four  { background: #dce319aa; grid-area: four;  }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
<hr><p>Three and Four should fill the space:</p>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have a fixed width, then you are saying "Hold my space" to the browser!

Comment: Grid is designed for when you know the layout ahead of time, so it's not the right layout tech to use for this kind of thing where you don't know the layout ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex is probably a better idea, but it is also quite possible to do it easily with the grid. This solution is based on fact that min-content will set second column width to 0, since there is no item there.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: min-content min-content auto auto;
}

.one   { background: #404788aa; width: 8rem }
.two   { background: #287d8eaa; width: 8rem }
.three { background: #3cbb75aa; grid-column: 3; }
.four  { background: #dce319aa; grid-column: 4; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
<hr><p>Three and Four should fill the space:</p>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `display: flex` with `flex` attributes like this:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.one   { background: #404788aa; flex: 0 1 8rem; }
.two   { background: #287d8eaa; flex: 0 1 8rem; }
.three { background: #3cbb75aa; flex: 1 1 auto; }
.four  { background: #dce319aa; flex: 1 1 auto; }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
<hr><p>Three and Four should fill the space:</p>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This solution merges the 3 and 4 column layout to a 5 column layout and uses a css trick to detect which class to use on the divs based on a certain existence and order. Then adjust the divs manually with grid-column property to align as needed.**

This is horrible and it is absolutely not scalabe, but it uses grid and css only to solve the problem.

After reviewing my solution I was hesitant to share it at all, but then I thought it will be a good alternative to show how the flex solution (provided by @ng-hobby) is much better than this.

As @TylerH said the grid system is not a perfect solution since you have to define a structure before actually knowing how many elements you want to fit into that structure.

This is a visual to show how the 3 and 4 column layouts end up when merged together. The vertical lines show the grid lines and the numbers below are the names of those.

```
4 column layout

|  8rem  |  8rem  |  1fr (50% - 8rem)  |  1fr (50% - 8rem)  |
|        |        |                    |                    |

3 column layout

|  8rem  |    1fr (50% - 4rem)    |    1fr (50% - 4rem)     |
|        |                        |                         |

5 column (mixed) layout

|        |        |               |    |                    |
1        2        3               4    5                    6
|  8rem  |  8rem  |  50% - 12rem  |4rem|    50% - 8rem      |
```

From this we can calculate the grid-template-columns property.
Note that I needed to switch to percents because calc() does not work with fr.

The (+) in css is called "Adjacent Sibling Selector" which in this case is used to apply a css rule when certain divs are next to one another.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 8rem 8rem calc(50% - 12rem) 4rem calc(50% - 8rem) ;
}

.one   { background: #404788aa; grid-column: 1 / 2; }
.two   { background: #287d8eaa; grid-column: 2 / 3; }
.two + .three { background: #3cbb75aa; grid-column: 3 / 5; }
.three { background: #3cbb75aa; grid-column: 2 / 4; }
.four  { background: #dce319aa; grid-column: 4 / 6; }
.two + .three + .four { background: #dce319aa; grid-column: 5 / 6; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr><p>Three and Four should fill the space:</p>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```